# the line number while reading file needs to be skipped accordingly(read more)

Tags: java, string, jsp, bufferedreader

i wish to read multiple files with multiple lines and read the files one by one. and from every file i want every 3rd line to be stored in an string array( i.e. line number 1,4,7,10,.... and so on must be stored in the string array) i tried this code but it still saves every line of all three files in the array. but i want to skip two lines and add every third line in the array.
help me out here.

here is the code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class music {
public double xx[] = new double[5];
public String songs[] = new String[40000];
//public static File f = new File("C:/Users/Prashant/Desktop/OCEAN/f.txt");
public static File[] fileList1 = new File("C:/Users/Prashant/Desktop/MUSIC/Categories").listFiles();

public void selectsongs() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException //, NoSuchElementException
{
    int i;
    int lineno = 1;
    int songno = 0;
    String t = "";
    xx[0]=51;
    xx[1]=10;
    xx[2]=60;
    xx[3]=60;
    xx[4]=60;

    if (xx[0] >= 50 && xx[1] < 50 && xx[2] >= 50 && xx[3] >= 50 && xx[4] >= 50) {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(fileList1[i]);
            lineno = 1;
            while (scanner1.hasNextLine()) {
                t = "";
                if (lineno % 3 == 1) {
                    t = t + scanner1.nextLine();
                    songs[songno] = t;
                    songno++;
                }
                lineno++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int j=0;j<songno;j++)
    {
        System.out.println(songs[j]);
    }
}
public static void main(String args[])
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Scanner` will only advance by a line if you call `nextLine`. `hasNextLine` does not affect the state. So you must call `nextLine` in every iteration of the while loop but only place the return value in the array when appropriate.

Comment: thanks so much its works, but there was a problem that it doesn't read all the files there must be some problem with 3 of the files. i'll check that out. thank you so much

Comment: Well your loop says `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {` so it'll only look at 3 files. Replace `3` with `fileList1.length` or better yet turn the loop into `for (File file : fileList1) { Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(file); ... }`.